# Common HTTP request delegate pattern in Objective-c (iOS)

Tags: ios, delegates, uiviewcontroller, singleton, httprequest

I have a view controller "myViewController" that makes HTTP requests.  I set the request's delegates to `self` (the instance of myViewController).  Everything works fine until I pop myViewController off the navigation stack before a request returns.  In this case the request tries to send a message to the dealloc'd myViewController (which causes my app to crash).

Currently I'm patching/solving this problem by setting the delegate of all requests to `nil` in myViewController's `dealloc` method.  **What's a better way to do this?**

Perhaps a singleton could be responsible for handling all HTTP requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago I had this same problem for UIWebView delegate events.  The solution is to keep track of all outgoing HTTP requests within your `myViewController`.  So, keep an instance variable called `mutableRequests` onto which you add every request that you send.  It will probably also be a good idea to remove requests from this array once they are finished.

In the `-viewWillUnload` method, simply enumerate through `mutableRequests` and cancel every request.  This will not only allow you to cancel all requests before your view is deallocated, but it will also help you respect the release/retain programming model by retaining all of the objects in an array while they are in use.

Comment: This approach can work.  Good to pay attention to what happens when a request is cancelled.  For example some requests may send the view controller a message calling requestCancelled (or similar).  Think it's possible for this message to be sent after the view controller is dealloc'd.

Comment: The only way to pick up on this message after `myViewController` is dealloc'd is to have the HTTP requests report to a different delegate, such as a global object or the app delegate.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're view controller is doing. If the requests are only relevant in that VC, then do what Alex is suggesting. If your app revolves around the requests (central part of functionality), you'll probably want that singleton. You'd probably also want a common delegate that all your view controllers implement, so that whatever is the present view controller can handle your delegate call. Obviously, your request-handling singleton will serve as the actual delegate of your requests, and call *your* delegate methods as necessary.